# Responsiveness of my webpage breaks on zoom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having issues with the responsiveness of my webpage.

The first image is of the webpage normally.
The second image shows text overflowing off the page instead of wrapping and staying within view.
The third image shows the bottom of the webpage where more overflowing takes place, resulting in a white gap between the content and the bottom of the page, which I don't want.
I've tried scouring google for a solution but haven't found any. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the [live demo](https://ganznz.github.io/sign-up-form/) if anyone wants to view the DOM and code. I have only used HTML and CSS. I'm aware everything is quite large, I'll be resizing it later.

*P.S. This is a mockup design, it's not a real form.*
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should size your elements using `vw` or `hw`units, this is what is causing an issue here. One way to have a consistant page is set a `min-width` to your body :

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
```

and then, sizing your element according to the body using either the `%`unit, or the `rem`unit.